# Is two-punctured torus a double cover of four-punctured sphere?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

There are few things I superficially know, which I do not know how to make a coherent statement through them.

1. By pair-of-pants decomposition, we know that the four-punctured sphere can be obtained by gluing two three-punctured sphere. Similarly, one punctured torus is obtained by self-gluing a three-punctured sphere, and two punctured torus is obtained by gluing two three-punctured sphere two times.
2. The torus is a double cover of a 2-sphere with four ramification points.
3. The Riemann-Hurwitz formula gives the relationship between the Euler characteristics of two un-punctured Riemann surfaces $S,S'$ where $S'$ is a ramification covering of order $n$ of the $S$.
   $$\chi(S')=n\chi(S)$$.

My question is: Is two-punctured torus a double cover of four-punctured sphere??

Comment: Suppose,  $p\colon S_{1,2}\to S_{1,4}$ is a two-fold cover. Then $p$ is a proper map as it is finite fold. Also, $p$ is surjective. So, $p$ induces a surjective map on the space ends, i.e., we have a surjective map $\text{Ends}(S_{1,2})\to \text{Ends}(S_{1,4})$, in other words, we have a surjective map from a set of two elements to a set of four elements.

Comment: More generally, a proper map of non-zero degree between two orientable connected surfaces induces a surjective map on the space of ends.

Comment: I think your comments are saying that four-punctured torus cannot be a double cover of two punctured torus. Is that correct?

Comment: @User Sorry, I think I wrote the wrong question. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Yeah, your title and original questions were misleading. Anyway, my first comment shows there is **no**  finite-fold cover from the twice punctured torus to four punctured torus. In case you are looking for a two-fold covering map $q\colon S_{1,2}\to S_{0,4}$ again note that such a map is a proper and surjection, so induces a surjection on the space of ends. That is the process is the same as it is said in my second comment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Does that mean, since proper surjection induces a surjection on the ends, that $S_{1,n}->S_{0,n}$ is the only possible finite coverings? But, isn't $S_{1,0}$ not a double cover of $S_{0,n}$? I understand that $S_{g,s}$ is the Riemann surface with $g$ genus and $s$ punctures.

Comment: @User: That looks like an actual answer to me, rather than a comment.

Comment: @Nugi: As for your last followup question, the possible coverings of $S_{0,n}$ which are **not** ruled out by the "space of ends" analysis are $S_{g,m}$ where $m \ge n$. Also, your Euler characteristic formula in item 3 is not correct. It is not valid for $S$ and $S'$ themselves; it is instead valid for the punctured versions where the all points in $S$ over which the map $S' \mapsto S$ is ramified are removed, as are all their pre-images in $S'$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for your answer. If I can, I want to know what would prevent the $S_{1,2}$ to be a double cover of $S_{0,4}$.

Comment: That is already answered in the comments of @User.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm sorry. I mean the other way around: can $S_{0,4}$ be a double cover of $S_{1,2}$? (I cannot see immediately. This probably will be the last question!)